# Regex Validation with Arrow Keys enabled

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, keycode

I wanted to do a PAN card validation on an input field. The pattern would be XXXXXNNNNX where X=Alphabet and N=Number. Also no special characters can be alowed.

The following code is the function I called on blur event  of the text field.

```
        function checkField(fieldname) {

        if (/^[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z]{1}$/.test(fieldname.value)) {

            //hiding error message
            $('#err_msgpan').hide();

            //removing error input class
            $(fieldname).removeClass('input_outlineerror');

            //adding normal input class
            $(fieldname).addClass('input_outline');

         } else {
            $('#err_msgpan').show();
            $(fieldname).removeClass('input_outline');
            $(fieldname).addClass('input_outlineerror');
            fieldname.focus();
            return false;
         }
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that the field now doesn't accept any ARROW keys, HOME key, END key.

I tried using Key Codes and Regex together but somehow it doesn't work. Please help me as to how this could be achieved.

Comment: Is that because of `return false;`? Create live demo.

Comment: remove the `{1}`, it's useless.

Comment: @Tushar, check here:  http://craftux.design/angel/step1.html

Removed return false; yet not working.